# Convert interface into Function parameters in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, types, interface

What I wanted to know is if it is possible to use an interface to describe the parameters that need to be passed to a function. An example would be the following:

```
  interface Person {
      name: string;
      age: number;   
  }

  function createPerson(name: string, age: number) {}
```

I'd like to use the *Person* interface as a reference for the *createPerson* parameters. So far, I've been using this:

```
function createPerson(name: Person['name'], age: Person['age']) {}
```

While it's better than nothing I still don't know if it is the best way for me to do this, since I still need to rewrite all parameter names. Is there a better option? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not an answer to the question you actually *asked*, but: Have you considered accepting an object? E.g., `function createPerson(person: Person)` (or `function createPerson({name, age}: Person)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm 99.9% sure there isn't a way to "spread" an interface's type definitions like that, not least because interfaces don't have an order while function parameters do.

You can do what you've shown in your question, or accept a `Person` object instead, either directly:

```
function createPerson(person: Person) { /* ... */ }
```

or with destructuring:

```
function createPerson({name, age}: Person) { /* ... */ }
```

Either way, you'd call it with an object, e.g.:

```
const createdPerson = createPerson({name: "Aylton Almeida", age: 20});
```

Comment: Yeah I was looking for this "spread" interface or anything like that. For me it's not a good option to accept the whole object but it's better than nothing. Tnks.

Comment: @AyltonAlmeida - I wanted this myself today and wondered...TypeScript is so incredibly flexible...maybe there's something...? So I pinged [Titian Cernicova Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir), a TypeScipt expert, and he confirmed that there's no way to do it (at least, nothing you could rely on across TypeScript builds).

Comment: @AyltonAlmeida - FWIW, you can go the other way (slightly) via the [`Parameters` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype). So if you have (say) `function foo(a: string, b: number): string;`, then `type FooParameters = Parameters<typeof foo>` is the tuple type `[a: string, b: number]` (a labelled tuple, but you can't access tuple labels in the type system or code).

Answer (score 0):

You could make is so that function accepts 1 object as opposed to 2 separate args. For example, you can do this.

`function createPerson(p: Person) {}`